# OpenLayers redraw not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

I have been googling around awhile just to try get my map to redraw once I have set a new label on my vector. If I zoom in and out the label does work correctly, but I'd like it to refresh on a click function.

```
               $(".openlayerLabel").change(function(){
                    var theValue = $(this).val();
                    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        console.log('Checkbox checked');
                        plugins.search.setStyles(true);
                        plugins.search.selectLayer.refresh({force:true});
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('Checkbox unchecked');
                    }
                });
```

What does NOT work is .refresh (rest is working just fine). I saw someone write that I should use force:true so I did try this but nothing happened really. I have also  tried .redraw but this gives similar result.

Any headsup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked on an OpenLayers project a while ago so I'm a bit rusty, but if I recall correctly you may need to loop through all of the features in the layer and explicitly call `layer.drawFeature(feature)` on all of them. Something like this:

```
var features = plugins.search.selectLayer.features;
for(var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
  plugins.search.selectLayer.drawFeature(features[i]);
}
```

Documentation here: http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.drawFeature

There's also a "redraw" method on the base layer class, so you can try:

```
plugins.search.selectLayer.redraw();
```

Documentation here: http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.redraw

Hopefully one of these two methods works!

Comment: I do get vectors showned on map, but when I look at "features" its array is 0 nothing in there?

Comment: When you say that there are "vectors" shown on the map, what class are you referring to? As far as I know, a vector and a feature are the same thing: http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Feature/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.OpenLayers.Feature.Vector